# How to add conditional comments for IE when including CSS / JS?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, css

I am transforming a HTML template into a Joomla template. I have the following block in HTML:

```
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

What is the best way of putting this conditional statement in a JDocument object?

Comment: What about leave the code as is? Should we use `JDocument` object anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following should work just fine:

```
<?php $doc = JFactory::getDocument(); ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<?php
    $doc->addScript('https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js');
    $doc->addScript('https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js');
?>
<![endif]-->
```

Note that I've defined `$doc` outside the statement, just in case you require it elsewhere.

### Update for example:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: addScript will at the files to an array and later render them along with other files. The conditional comments will be left outside. So this does not work. But thanks!

Comment: Ahh fair enough. Just out of curiosity, why do you want to use JDocument to import scripts from a CDN? Surely the code you posted in your question would suffice

Comment: It helps me avoid conflicts / order of loading if I can load them all with JDocument. Anyway the code itself could also be local not just from a CDN.

Comment: Personally, I always load these script via CDN using normal script tags then below that, use `<jdoc:include type="head" />` so the other script that are imports using JDocument are always imported after.I've provided an example in my answer to show you. This is also how it's done in the Protostar template however they decided to import html5shiv after rather than before

Answer (score 4):

It looks like JDocument (actually JDocumentHTML) has a hidden method: `addCustomTag`.

```
$customTag = <<<CUSTOM
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
CUSTOM;
$doc->addCustomTag($customTag);
```